# anchor tag question for Typecript Angular

Tags: angular, accessibility, href, anchor

`<a id="supportLink" (click)="navigate(url.state)">click</a>`

I'm doing some accessibility work on some existing code. I have some anchor tags with click events bound to them. I noted there is no href attribute here either because the click event properly handles to route and clicking enter on the keyboard also triggers the even. I want this to be tabbable, but because there's is no href attribute it isn't tabbable, so I added a tabindex="0. This now made my a tag tabbable, but now clicking enter on the keyboard is not triggering my event. I've found that adding the following code to my a tag keys the click event working properly clicking it or pressing enter.

`href="javascript:void(0)"`

Is this acceptable code for accesibility standards?...or does someone recommend a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(keydown)="EnterSubmit($event, url.state)` in tag.

And in .ts :

```
EnterSubmit(e,state){
     if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      alert("Submitted with enter.")
   }
}
```

**Addition to above**

You also need to set focus on you anchor tag.
You can achieve that with viewChild or simple DOM way is :

```
document.getElementById("supportLink")?.focus();
```

If you want this focus on page load, Write this in ngAfterViewInit().
Final HTML code :

```
<a id="supportLink" (click)="navigate(url.state)" (keydown)="EnterSubmit($event, url.state)" tabindex="0">click</a>`
```